# Cntk personal dataset

Tags: python, dataset, cntk

I have read the cntk tutorials but I can not find a way to structure and create my image dataset.
In tutorials they use, like the mnist dataset, files like mean.xml, map.txt and other files for labels and features. I can not find other guides on how to generate these files based on the folder, for example (positive and negative) from which to obtain file mapping and serialization of images in the format | labels | features|.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small Python program to create these files for yourself e.g. the map file can be done with an `os.walk` or some calls to `glob`. Similarly the mean.xml can be constructed using `PIL` and `minidom` as in [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Image/DataSets/CIFAR-10/cifar_utils.py).